# How do I resize an alternate layout in InDesign CC (15.1.2)

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, layout

I created an alternate layout and realised the width of the page is 5mm shorter than I'd like. I cannot find any option to resize the alternate layout.

I've tried Document Set-Up and Adjust Layout, but those are only resizing the original layout and not the alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to the pages palette.

Make sure you have the page you want to change highlighted.

Click on the "Edit Page Size" icon on at the bottom and select "Custom".

Enter the new size and click OK.

[image: how to resize page]